# Momentarily disable buttons enabled through dependency properties

Tags: wpf, button, dependency-properties

I have the following:

```
    <Button Content="Do XXX" Height="23" Name="btnXXX"
                  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=(Model:INameOfInterface.CanDoXXX)}" />
    <Button Content="Do YYY" Height="23" Name="btnYYY"
                  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=(Model:INameOfInterface.CanDoYYY)}" />
```

Working very nicely, btnXXX is enabled or disabled according to whether the interface can do XXX, btnYYY similarly for YYY.

However, to force one action per click, I want to disable all the buttons once one of them is clicked, i.e. momentarily override the dependencies and disable the buttons and then, once action has been executed, re-establish the dependency conditions.

So my question is: **How do I momentarily disable all buttons and then resume the dependencies**

Comment: Do you mean re-enabling buttons as soon as the action is completed?

Comment: Yes, but according to the properties. Of course, I could manually disable all and then do for each button: btnYYY.enabled = INameOfTheInterface.CanDoYYY, but that would defeat the whole dependency property purpose i.e. it should be without coding...

Comment: You can create the bool property and bind all buttons IsEnable with it. Whenever u do some action , make it false and after completing the action make it true which in turn will affect all the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you don't "override and resume dependency properties", but design Model/ViewModel so that a property you bind to encapsulates all required states. In your case this would mean that your `Model:INameOfInterface.CanDoXXX` should be true initially, and be false whenever **any** button action is being executed (xxx, yyy, ...). So your `CanDoXXX` would have to know about execution of `YYY`. It might be a bad idea to mix it all up in your Model and this is where ViewModel comes into play.

Assume your Model instances are only self-aware: `CanDoXXX` is false **only** if `XXX` is being executed. You can have a ViewModel class containing a collection of models, each with its individual state. Now, all you need is to put a property in VM, e.g. `CanExecuteAny` that would iterate over all models and check whether any of them is doing work (`CanDoXXX`, `CanDoYYY` indicate that). Finally bind

```
<Button IsEnabled={Binding CanExecuteAny} />
```

This is just one of potential solutions and the best one depends on exact structure of your data. Here are some other thoughts:

- You could put all your buttons in a panel and disable the panel instead of individual buttons.
- Implement `ICommand` interface and bind button's `Command` property to it. See `RelayCommand` concept. Personally I'd go for it.
- Since your buttons need info whether any other button has been clicked, you might find it useful to have sort of a global state accessible to all models (perfectly dependency injection; less perfectly a singleton without DI).

Having said that, the basic idea is to have all needed info in a single property you can bind to. Swaping DPs is not really a way it was designed to work. The `Binding` is already there to update things, so setting it more than once is repeating the same job twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the bool property and bind all buttons IsEnable with it. Whenever u do some action , make it false and after completing the action make it true which in turn will affect all the buttons. OR u can use spinner/Busy indicator.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you answer :(
Consider btnXXX. I want it to depend on the CanDoXXX property - When the property is true, the button should be enabled. When the property is false, the button should be disabled. This is easy. However, I addionally want that just after any button is clicked, till the click event handler returns, all the buttons should be disabled.